# XSL 1.0 Insert Multiple Attribute Values into a single one

Tags: xml, xslt

so here's a basic example of a XML that i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project>
    <ProductPool>
        <Product Type="A">
            <PagePool>
                <Page Number="1"/>
                <Page Number="2"/>
            </PagePool>
        </Product>
        <Product Type="B">
            <PagePool>
                <Page Number="1"/>
                <Page Number="2"/>
            </PagePool>
        </Product>
    </ProductPool>
</Project>
```

I wanted to have a for-each loop that reads the numbers attribute and adds each element specific page attributes into one so the desired result would look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project>
    <UnboundComponent PageSequence="1 2"/>
    <BoundComponent PageSequence="1 2"/>
</Project>
```

Unfortunatly i always get "Number="1 2 1 2" in both Components.

Heres the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="Project">
            <xsl:for-each select="//Product">
                <xsl:variable name="elem-name">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test='@Type="B"'>BoundComponent</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>UnboundComponent</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$elem-name}">
                    <xsl:attribute name="PageSequence">
                        <xsl:for-each select="/Project/ProductPool/Product/PagePool/Page">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@Number"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the `select` attribute of your inner `for-each` statement. At that point in the stylesheet, the context node is a `Product` (because you are inside a `<xsl:for-each select="//Product">` statement). But your inner `for-each` statement's `select` expression starts with a `/` which means it starts searching from the *root* of the document, and that's why it finds all the `Page` elements.

I have changed it, below, so that the inner `for-each` statement's `select` attribute contains an XPath that's evaluated relative to the `Product`, i.e. just `PagePool/Page`, which therefore returns only `Page` elements that are children of `PagePool` elements that are children of the current ("context") node.

I also moved the `<xsl:text> </xsl:text>` to be *inside* the `for-each` instead of *after* it, since I think you wanted to insert spaces *between* each of the numbers.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="Project">
            <xsl:for-each select="//Product">
                <xsl:variable name="elem-name">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test='@Type="B"'>BoundComponent</xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>UnboundComponent</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:element name="{$elem-name}">
                    <xsl:attribute name="PageSequence">
                        <xsl:for-each select="PagePool/Page">
                            <xsl:if test="position() &gt; 1">
                               <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@Number"/>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked wonders.
Is there a way to remove the last white space created by the <xsl:text> so it doesnt turn out "1 2 " but rather "1 2"? Since its in the loop now.

Comment: I will edit to remove the trailing space...

Answer (score 0):

You could add a predicate filter to test whether the `@Number` value is equal to any of the `preceding::Page/@Number` values, and exclude if it's a repeat:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/Project/ProductPool/Product/PagePool/Page/@Number[not(. = preceding::Page/@Number)]">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

With XSLT 2.0 (and greater), you could just select all of the `@Number` and use `distinct-values()`:

```
<xsl:attribute name="PageSequence" select="distinct-values(/Project/ProductPool/Product/PagePool/Page/@Number)"/>
```